# Emacs lisp, skeleton-mode: Prevent trailing newline

Tags: emacs, latex, elisp, template-engine

I am using this code for inserting `\emph{..}` blocks into latex:

```
(define-skeleton mylatex-emph-skeleton "\emph{_}"
  nil "\\emph{" _ "}")
```

As an undired side effect however, it also inserts a newline at the end of the skeleton. E.g. if I select `emphasized` in

```
This is emphasized text.
```

and press my hotkey, I end up with

```
This is \emph{emphasized}
text.
```

instead of

```
This is \emph{emphasized} text.
```

Can I prevent this? Note that the newline only gets inserted, there is text after the insertion point, so it is not as easy as deleting the character after the closing `}`.

Comment: Why not just use a modern tool instead, like `yasnippet`?

Comment: Because skeleton is much less bulky.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Set `skeleton-end-newline` to `nil` to change the behavior of all skeletons.

Modify `skeleton-end-hook` to check which skeleton is being expanded and inserting newline as desired if you want to change the behavior of a specific skeleton.

Comment: It solves the problem for the one skeleton at the cost of changing the behaviour of other skeletons, where the behaviour is intended. So, no solution that is specific to a single skeleton? :-/

Comment: You did not say that you want the behavior of a single skeleton changed (see edit).